# How to decide what goes in the Domain or Application Project in a "DDD" solution?

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design

I am learning about DDD and domain-centric architecture design applied to .NET solutions.

However, I am struggling a bit about how to implement it.

I have some examples that came up to my mind recently:

- Filter/converting an excel file to another another kind of file  json/xml and formatted following some business rules, be it a Console application or a WebAPI
- Computing the energy deployed or the distance given some train stations

How to decide what goes into the Application "layer" and the Domain "layer"?

I read:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/140999/application-layer-vs-domain-layer
- https://github.com/thiagolunardi/MvcMusicStoreDDD
- https://github.com/rafaelfgx/DotNetArchitecture
- https://github.com/EduardoPires/EquinoxProject
- https://github.com/ardalis/ddd-guestbook
- https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb
- https://github.com/HudsonLima/Product-API
- https://github.com/thangchung/magazine-website
- https://github.com/gigiogodoi/Blackbird
- https://github.com/JasonGT/DDDBNE2017
- https://github.com/felipeolimpos/base-core-ddd-mvc-ef-pg-ioc-proj
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/ddd-oriented-microservice

Answer (score 2):

**The Domain layer** contains all the code that enforces business rules.

It should be  technology agnostic (like specific databases - sql, no sql - or protocols - HTTP, REST) and frameworks agnostic. This means that it looks the same whether the Aggregates are persisted in an SQL database or in a NoSQL database, it is called from a HTTP controller or from a console application.

It should be [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), with no side-effects. This implies it should not do any `I/O` (read or write from any files). It receives all the data it needs as method arguments. For me, passing an infrastructure or application layer as argument to an Aggregate method call is also bad, even it is hidden behind a domain `interface`, because it can do `I/O`.

It should not depend on any other Layers. This means no `imports` or `use`  from other layers (or whatever programming language construct you use in your programming language).

**The Application layer** is a thin layer that loads an Aggregate from the Repository, it calls the corresponding method on the Aggregate and then it persist the Aggregate to the Repository. It basically glues the Domain with the Infrastructure.

Comment: thanks for you answer. I start to understand. Let's say I am reading a csv file and checking the sum of two given columns and if above a certain threshold concatenate two other columns. Reading the csv file would be then entirely in the infrastructure / application layer (not that thin?) ? and the Specification pattern (checking if two values are above a given threshold) and the concatenation would be in the Domain layer?

Comment: @Nolwenn reading the file would be in the Infrastructure. That checking and concatenation would be in the Domain layer. It depends a lot on your details, I don't know for sure, but most probable your Aggregate would not care that the data comes from a csv file, it would see it as a list  of vectors

Comment: Isn't the Application layer above the Domain/Business Layer? I would assume then that it links the Presentation Layer with the Business Layer, and not the Business Layer with the Infrastructure! Can you clarify that please?

Comment: @binte what you are describing is the *Strict* Layered Architecture and I don't recommend it in general. In a relaxed architecture the Application layer may (and should) call both Domain and Infrastructure in order to glue them together.

Answer (score 0):

In DDD architecture all the business logics and rules should be within the Domain layer. Application layer is responsible for referring the business logic by accessing Domain layer and do database updates through Infrastructure layer. So it is clear if you are goin to add a business rule or logic it should be Domain layer